# why is it running me this Error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'?

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
# Global variable for flash cards
flash_cards = {}


def read_flash_cards_from_text_file():
    """Will read line by line the card name and definition from a local txt file"""
    global flash_cards

    with open("/Users/falks/pyproject1/my_env/Quizlet/flash_cards.txt", "r") as f:
     for lines in f:
         lines_stripped = lines.strip()
         index_split = lines_stripped.index("=")
         key = lines_stripped[0:index_split].strip()
         values = lines_stripped[index_split+1:].strip()
         flash_cards[key] = values
    print(flash_cards)



    if len(flash_cards) < 4:
         print("You must have at least 4 flash cards in text file before starting Quizlet, exiting program now")
         sys.exit()



#read_flash_cards_from_text_file()
def update_flash_cards(key, values, save_to_file=True, delete_flash_card=False):
    """Will be called whenever adding or deleting or replacing a flash card"""
    global flash_cards
    if delete_flash_card:
        del flash_cards[key]

    if save_to_file:
        write_flash_cards_to_text_file()



def write_flash_cards_to_text_file():
    """Will line by line write the name and definition for each flash card to a file for saving"""
    global flash_cards

    with open("./flash_cards.txt", "w+") as f:
        for l, f in flash_cards.items():
            f.write(l + "=" + f + "\n")



def add_flash_card():
    """Will be called from main menu to create or update flash card"""
    global flash_cards

    save_file = False
    while save_file is False:
     key = input("Write down your Name of the flash card: " )
     values = input("write down your defintion of the card name: ")
     save_to_file = input("are you sure y/n: ")
     if save_to_file == "n":
        continue
     if save_to_file == "y":
         save_to_file = True
         save_file = True
     return update_flash_cards(key, values, save_to_file)

read_flash_cards_from_text_file()

add_flash_card()
```

Can somebody pls explain me, why its running me this Error:

{'g': '5', 'f': '4', 'r': '6', 't': '12'}

Write down your Name of the flash card: w

write down your defintion of the card name: r

are you sure y/n: y

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\falks\pyproject1\my_env\Quizlet\QuitzletTry.py", line 88, in 
add_flash_card()
File "C:\Users\falks\pyproject1\my_env\Quizlet\QuitzletTry.py", line 77, in add_flash_card
return update_flash_cards(key, values, save_to_file)
File "C:\Users\falks\pyproject1\my_env\Quizlet\QuitzletTry.py", line 49, in update_flash_cards
write_flash_cards_to_text_file()
File "C:\Users\falks\pyproject1\my_env\Quizlet\QuitzletTry.py", line 59, in write_flash_cards_to_text_file
f.write(l + "=" + f + "\n")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

I dont get it, thanks for you help! it does delete the flash_cards.txt, but doesn't overwrite it.

if anyone wonders, i code a simple Quizlet programm for exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here. You are using same name for both the file object and loop variable. When you call `f.write(l + "=" + f + "\n")`, `f` is no longer a file object(Because the the loop variable overwritten `f` into a string object)

```
with open("./flash_cards.txt", "w+") as f:
    for l, f in flash_cards.items():
       f.write(l + "=" + f + "\n")
```

Comment: thx i changend it, but it doesnt add something to my textfile

Comment: @EvaIgoria Could you please update the latest code.

Comment: i did it like in the example under your answer

Comment: @EvaIgoria The code in my answer is from your question to point out the issue.

Comment: yeah you good, thx i will manage it on my own :)

Comment: i have found the mistake, in update_flash_cards i do not attend it to the dictionary ^^

Answer (score 0):

you have `f` in your `for` inside the `with`

You may choose another variable, and the problem will be removed. As example:

```
    with open("./flash_cards.txt", "w+") as f:
        for l, value in flash_cards.items():
            f.write(l + "=" + value + "\n")
```